# Can you help me with oop?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

This is my code:

```
Extractor.hpp
template <class O, class D> class Extractor{
  public:
    Extractor(
        std::vector<O>& input_data,
        Filtro<O>& filtro,
        Mapeador<O, D>& mapeador
    ): _input_data(input_data), _filtro(filtro), _mapeador(mapeador) {}

    unsigned int getData(std::vector<D>& output) {
      unsigned total = 0;
      for (O& data: _input_data) {
        if (_filtro.dadoValido(data)) {
          output.push_back(_mapeador.transformaDado(data));
          total++;
        }
      }
      return total;
    }

  private:

    std::vector<O>& _input_data;

    Filtro<O>& _filtro;

    Mapeador<O, D>& _mapeador;
};
```

```
Extractor.cpp
template <class NUM_TYPE>
class Num2Sqrt: public Mapeador<NUM_TYPE, NUM_TYPE> {
...
  }
};

class FiltroNumPositivo: public Filtro<NUM_TYPE> {
  bool dadoValido(NUM_TYPE& d) const override {
...
  }
};

template <class NUM_TYPE> void test_filter_square_roots() {
...

    Extractor<Filtro<int>,Mapeador<std::string, int>> new_extrator(new_filtro, new_mapeador, saida);
```

I just cut a little part of the code just to you all be capable to understand, but my problem is declaring the class of the template named Extractor, look at the extense error report(I cutted a little piece of the error):

> ExtratorDeDados.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void test_filter_square_roots() [with NUM_TYPE = int]’:
> ExtratorDeDados.cpp:329:37:   required from here
> ExtratorDeDados.cpp:243:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘ExtratorDeDados<Filtro, >Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >::ExtratorDeDados(Filtro*&, Mapeador<int, >int>*&, std::vector<Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >&)’
> ExtratorDeDados<Filtro,Mapeador<std::string, int>> new_extrator(new_filtro, new_mapeador, >saida);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> In file included from ExtratorDeDados.cpp:3:0:
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:124:5: note: candidate: ExtratorDeDados<O, D>::ExtratorDeDados(std::vector&, >Filtro&, Mapeador<O, D>&) [with O = Filtro; D = Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, >int>]
> ExtratorDeDados(
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:124:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Filtro*’ to >‘std::vector<Filtro, std::allocator<Filtro > >&’
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:113:35: note: candidate: constexpr ExtratorDeDados<Filtro, >Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >::ExtratorDeDados(const >ExtratorDeDados<Filtro, Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >&)
> template <class O, class D> class ExtratorDeDados {
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:113:35: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:113:35: note: candidate: constexpr ExtratorDeDados<Filtro, >Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >::ExtratorDeDados(ExtratorDeDados<Filtro, >Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >&&)
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:113:35: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
> ExtratorDeDados.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void test_filter_square_roots() [with NUM_TYPE = double]’:
> ExtratorDeDados.cpp:332:40:   required from here
> ExtratorDeDados.cpp:243:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘ExtratorDeDados<Filtro, >Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >::ExtratorDeDados(Filtro*&, Mapeador<int, >int>*&, std::vector<Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int> >&)’
> ExtratorDeDados<Filtro,Mapeador<std::string, int>> new_extrator(new_filtro, new_mapeador, >saida);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> In file included from ExtratorDeDados.cpp:3:0:
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:124:5: note: candidate: ExtratorDeDados<O, D>::ExtratorDeDados(std::vector&, >Filtro&, Mapeador<O, D>&) [with O = Filtro; D = Mapeadorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, >int>]
> ExtratorDeDados(
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:124:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Filtro*’ to >‘std::vector<Filtro, std::allocator<Filtro > >&’
> ExtratorDeDados.hpp:113:35: note: candidate: constexpr ExtratorDeDados<Filtro,
> I would be really thankful if anyone can help me!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your declaration:

```
template <class O, class D> class Extractor{
  public:
    Extractor(
        std::vector<O>& input_data,
        Filtro<O>& filtro,
        Mapeador<O, D>& mapeador
    ): _input_data(input_data), _filtro(filtro), _mapeador(mapeador) {}
```

Here's the call:

```
    Extractor<Filtro<int>,Mapeador<std::string, int>> new_extrator(new_filtro, new_mapeador, saida);
```

So, `O` is `Filtro<int>`, and `D` is `Mapeador<std::string, int>`.

This means the parameters have to be:

> ```
>     std::vector<Filtro<int>>& input_data,
>     Filtro<Filtro<int>>& filtro,
>     Mapeador<Filtro<int>, Mapeador<std::string, int>>& mapeador
> ```

But, as `std::vector<O>` you're passing `new_filtro` which is `Filtro<int>*`, and instead of `Mapeador<O, D>` you're passing `new_mapeador` which is `Mapeador<int, int>*`.

So the parameters don't match to your declared types.

Comment: Got a bit confused there with the parameters, but you get the gist

Comment: hmm i got what you did, but this is a college project and I can't change the .hpp file

Comment: @FabricioLopes the hpp file is fine. It's your usage of it that's not. Which is exactly what you should be fixing :-)

Comment: okay, thank u so mch

Comment: @FabricioLopes  Do you understand?  Sometimes something as simple as order of parameters in your call can yield huge error messages.  You have to program your code to the API, not change the API.

Comment: I understood but, I still cant get over this error even with the hints I've received, I changed the order of the parameters to the correct, but even when doing it I still receiving erros

Comment: @FabricioLopes it's not just the order, it's the type. Track what type is `O` and what type is `D` and match it to the prototype, you'll see the mismatch very quickly